# Show and hide image from shell

Tags: bash, shell

I have a large pile of scanned documents which I have to sort by the date printed on them, in different...

- locations
- types
- granularities ("2017, somewhere inbetween the first and 9th of July")
- formats ("2017-07-02", "2.7.17", "02.07.17", ...)

Only a human can do that.

I imagined some kind of shell script that

1. iterates over the files
2. somehow shows me the current file in a different window
3. lets me input the date in the correct format
4. closes the image display
5. prepends the date to the file name.

Number 1. is easy in bash:

```
    for scanFile in *.jpg; do echo "MAGIC"; done
```

Number 3. and 5. are easy as well:

```
    read -n 8 -p "Please enter date in YYYYMMDD: " theDate
    mv $scanfile $theDate--$scanfile
```

But what about numbers 2. and 4.? **How can I display an image from bash, without loosing focus on the terminal window, and with the ability to close it at will?**

If it works with cygwin shell, it is extra great, but that is no must-have.

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick's `display` does the trick.

I start a normal cygwin terminal, enlarge it to the left half of the screen, and start an X session via

```
startx /usr/bin/fvwm2 &
```

I move/resize that black X window to fit the right half of the screen and note the dimensions it mentions in the shell.

Then, all I have to do is to start ImageMagick's `display` command and kill it accordingly.

This is my written-on-the-fly code block:

```
staticYear="2019"
for scanFile in YYYY-MM-DD--*.png; do 
  display -display :0 -resize 952x1000 $scanFile &
  read -n 4 -p "Please enter date in MMDD: " theDate
  kill $(pidof display)
  if [ -z "$theDate" ]
  then
    echo -e "\nCancelling."
    break
  elif [ "0000" = "$theDate" ]
  then
    echo -e "\nSkipping that one."
  else
    echo -e "\nThe date: $theDate"
    echo "New filename: $staticYear$theDate-$scanFile"
    mv $scanFile "$staticYear$theDate-$scanFile"
  fi
done
```